# Generar un valor aleatorio dentro de arreglo bidimensional y poder consultar uno de los elementos que se generó

Tags: python, lista, random

Tengo un programa en Python que tiene un arreglo bidimensional de la siguiente forma:

```
[31 : 18 , 19 : 36 , 55 : 63 , 21 : 29 , 14 : 58 , 18 : 54 , 22 : 25 ]
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que se escoja un punto aleatorio dentro del arreglo bidimensional, para ello hice la siguiente línea de código:

```
initpoint = random.choice(main_array)
```

El cuál, si lo imprimo, se despliega de esta manera:

```
19 : 36
```

Lo que quiero hacer es poder consultar dentro del valor escogido aleatoriamente uno de los dos puntos, por ejemplo, si quiero imprimir o usar el valor 19 dentro del mismo en un algoritmo.

Por si se necesita, adjuntaré el código, lo que hace es leer los valores de un archivo txt y los convierte en un arreglo bidimensional clasificándolos como x & y.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random

fileName = open('outputfile1.txt','r')

main_array = []

class Array:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} : {} '.format(self.x, self.y)

def extract_values(line):
    a, b = line.split()
    return int(a), int(b)


with open('outputfile1.txt','r') as file:
    main_array = []

    n, p = extract_values(file.readline())
    for line in file.readlines():
        x, y = extract_values(line)
        
        main_array.append(Array(x, y))

initpoint = random.choice(main_array)
```

Comment: esto `19 : 36` se guarda como string?

Comment: porque eso no es una sintaxis válida

Comment: Eso supuse, si tienes otra sugerencia para escoger un valor aleatorio dentro del arreglo principal lo aceptaré con gusto. Por el momento es el único método que se me ocurrió.

Comment: podrías colocar tu archivo de texto por favor?

Comment: Claro, es un archivo .txt simple con el siguiente formato empezando desde la primera línea:   `7 3  
31 18  
19 36  
55 63  
21 29  
14 58  
18 54  
22 25` En donde se muestran dos espacios es un salto de línea, disculpa los inconvenientes, soy nuevo.

Comment: no te preocupes, muchas gracias, en un momento estaré publicando una respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo único que debes hacer es implementar el dunder method `__getitem__` que define que cosa regresar cuando se usa la notación de corchetes `[]` en una variable.

Tu clase quedaría así:

```py
class Array:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.value = [x,y]

    def __getitem__(self,i):
        return self.value[i] #retornamos el elemento en la posicion que se pida

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.value[0]} : {self.value[1]} '
```

Por cierto la lectura del archivo se puede hacer de forma normal con un `readlines`.

```py
main_array = []
with open('archivo.txt','r') as 
    for line in f.readlines():
        x, y = extract_values(line)
        main_array.append(Array(x, y))

initpoint = random.choice(main_array)
```

Y ahora si queremos acceder al primer número contenido en `initpoint` podemos hacer

```py
print(initpoint[0])
```

Y obtendremos el número sin problemas.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!